# Is it possible to get UID of a Mifare Classic or Desfire card by android phone with the Broadcom NFC chip?

Tags: android, nfc, uniqueidentifier, mifare, serial-number

I only need to get the UID of a Mifare classic or a Desfire card by the getId() function. I will not need any other read-write operations.

Can a smartphone with the broadcom NFC chip, read the UIDs of Mifare or Desfire cards?
I looked at the [Nexus 4 read Mifare Classic card UID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16912067/nexus-4-read-mifare-classic-card-uid) and [What mobile phones with NFC have full support of Mifare Classic (1K & 4K) cards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207526/what-mobile-phones-with-nfc-have-full-support-of-mifare-classic-1k-4k-cards) threads but there is no clear answer.

Did anyone try e.g. Samsung Galaxy Young 2 or Samsung Galaxy S3 Neo with the Mifare or Desfire?

Thanks :)

Comment: What's unclear about ["*You can call getId() on the Tag object in the Intent.*"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16928474/2425802) or ["*You can read the UID.*"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16914495/2425802)?

Comment: the "You cannot talk to the Mifare Classic chip using the Broadcom Chip" statement got me thinking about the Mifare part, unfortunatelly the Desfire and other cards (not directly supported by broadcom) were not mentioned whatsoever. Thats why I entered the question. Regards :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You just need to use method `getId()` from `android.nfc.Tag` (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/Tag.html#getId()) and you will get the UID no matter what NFC chipset you have on your phone. UID is not a Mifare-specific identifier, but one defined in ISO 14443-3, so all contactless cards shall provide it in the same way. OK, there are differences in TypeA and TypeB, but you get my point.

I have tested it on a Nexus 5, which I believe also has a Broadcom chipset. Please share your results when you test it on other terminals!

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. Ive tested it today on the mifare classic. It works like a charm with Samsung S4. Ill share the results with Desfire and other cards later after I test it.